# Unity - C#: How to fill up a 2D array with a spread of 1's or 0's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

Im building a game in unity that (theoretically) works by using a 2D array of boolean elements that then is processed to decide if there should be a block in that space in-game or not, however i'm having issues using unity to actually create said array. Currently my code is:

```
void Start () {
    System.Random rnd = new System.Random ();
    int MapCol = 9;
    int MapRow = 9;
    int [,] MapArray = new int [MapCol, MapRow];
    foreach (int i in MapArray)
        MapArray ["{0} ", i] = rnd.Next (0, 2);
    }
```

My issues are arising because the official microsoft answer on this question only explains how to use foreach on a 2D array to look at individual text elements, and not integers.

I am also attempting to push guidelines onto the map that is generated in post, which doesn't seem to work, as potentially infinite maps could be generated that do not fit these guidelines and the map could potentially never be finished. Currently these guidelines are that a block must be touching two adjacent blocks, and a block cannot be touching 3 blocks in the same corner, i.e.

> - 1 1 0
> - 1 1 0 this placement is not allowed
> - 0 0 0

meanwhile

> - 0 1 0
> - 1 1 1 this placement is allowed.
> - 0 0 0

help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
So, to further explain the generation conditions. I want for every "1" to be touching another two 1's minimum, and what is considered touching here is in the 4 cardinal directions, up, down, left and right. Diagonal contact with another 1 is fine, unless that diagonal is surrounded by another 2 "1"'s. so an arrangement where 4 blocks are grouped together should not be possible. so the pattern of:

> 1 1
>   1 1

should never occur within the grid

Comment: @ChuckSavage You should never make assumptions about what undefined variables will "default to". This is not good programming practice and the time saved in speed is likely not worth the risk.

Comment: Additionally, Unity3d provides a Random class. Use `Random.Range(0,N)`

Comment: @8protons [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) `The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null.`

Comment: @Kevin hamill, Do you want the code to generate one single solution OR all possible solutions for a given 2D array size?

Comment: @Mukesh Saini Just one single random solution, All solutions is an extremely interesting concept though. Both would be really nice to know, but one single solution is the one that im looking for as of now

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you may be interested in watching the tutorial "[Procedural Cave Generation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial)" they go over how to randomly generate maps using a seed with rules.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multidimensional arrays, it's better to stick to nested `for` loops, like these:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MapArray.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < MapArray.GetLength(1); j++) {
        MapArray[i, j] = rnd.Next(0, 2);
    }           
}
```

Regarding your second question, can you elaborate on the condition? I didn't understand it completely.

Comment: Thank you! i added a short explanation of the conditions, feel free to attempt to fulfill them if they make more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm that fulfills the guidelines and generates one possible solution based on provided seed -

```
// 2D array Map
var blocks = [];
// size of 2D array Map
var sizeX = 9,
    sizeY = 9;
// seed - as a starting point in 2d array within range of array size-1. eg. (2,1) , (5,5)
var seedX = 8,
    seedY = 8;
// used to hold 2D array elements to be processed
var processX = [];
var processY = [];
// string used for output
var str = "";

// initialize 2D array with value 2 and set seed to block as 1
function initializeMap() {
    for (var row = 0; row < sizeX; row++) {
        blocks[row] = [];
        for (var col = 0; col < sizeY; col++) {
            blocks[row][col] = 2;
        }
    }
    blocks[seedX][seedY] = 1;
}

// print the 2D array map with guidelines
function printMap() {
    str = "1. Every 1 is surrounded by atleast two 1s.<br/>";
    str += "2. No 1 is surrounded by three 1s in the same corner.<br/><br/>";
    for (var row = 0; row < sizeX; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < sizeY; col++) {
            str += blocks[row][col] + " ";
        }
        str += "\n<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}

// Add current element's unprocessed siblings to processing stack and set its value to -1
function pushSiblingsToProcess(x, y) {
    for (var row = x - 1; row <= x + 1; row++) {
        if (row >= 0 && row < sizeY) {
            for (var col = y - 1; col <= y + 1; col++) {
                if (col >= 0 && col < sizeX && blocks[row][col] > 1) {
                    processX.push(row);
                    processY.push(col);
                    blocks[row][col] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// sets the current element to make is either block as 1 or empty as 0
function setBlock(x, y) {
    var totalAdj = 0;
    var prev = false;
    if ((x - 1) >= 0 && blocks[x - 1][y] == 1) {
        totalAdj += 1;
        prev = true;
    }
    if ((y - 1) >= 0 && blocks[x][y - 1] == 1) {
        totalAdj += 1;
        if (prev && (x - 1) >= 0 && blocks[x - 1][y - 1] == 1) {
            blocks[x][y] = 0;
            return;
        }
        prev = true;
    } else {
        prev = false;
    }
    if ((x + 1) < sizeX && blocks[x + 1][y] == 1) {
        totalAdj += 1;
        if (prev && (y - 1) >= 0 && blocks[x + 1][y - 1] == 1) {
            blocks[x][y] = 0;
            return;
        }
        prev = true;
    } else {
        prev = false;
    }
    if ((y + 1) < sizeY && blocks[x][y + 1] == 1) {
        totalAdj += 1;
        if (prev && (x + 1) <= sizeX && blocks[x + 1][y + 1] == 1) {
            blocks[x][y] = 0;
            return;
        }
        prev = true;
    } else {
        prev = false;
    }
    if (prev && (x - 1) >= 0 && (y + 1) < sizeY && blocks[x - 1][y + 1] == 1 && blocks[x - 1][y] == 1) {
        blocks[x][y] = 0;
        return;
    }
    blocks[x][y] = 1;
}

// called recursively to set blocks until processing stack has elements to process
function generateMap() {
    if (processX.length <= 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        var currX = processX.pop();
        var currY = processY.pop();
        setBlock(currX, currY);
        pushSiblingsToProcess(currX, currY);
        generateMap();
    }
}

initializeMap();
pushSiblingsToProcess(seedX, seedY);
generateMap();
printMap();
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1090/gdk0m1kv/3/)

Comment: So, i will probably comment again later once i have read a lot more of this and have more things I need clarified, but as a first; im assuming that randomizing seedX and seedY would make this come out with different values, while right now it would always give me the same one?

Comment: In JSFiddle you can change the seedX & seedY value and it'll start the process by creating that seed block as 1 and will provide you a different solution. :)

Comment: Yes, randomizing seed will give you different results.

Comment: Okay this is wonderful! thank you for taking the time, but i have noticed some seeds didnt meet the guidelines. on a 9*9 grid using 3, 3 as the seed blocks appear that dont touch two adjacent blocks (specifically the block in the bottom right) and it would be convenient to have a link to this that doesnt then print the seed as well, even though i can most definitely get rid of the printing on my own.

Comment: When seed is (3,3) the bottom right block has 1s on it's left and left-top corner. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms1090/gdk0m1kv/4/)

Comment: Sorry if i didn't make it clear, the two touching blocks were intended to be touching on either the left, right, top or bottom of a block